Placeholder issue with Textarea when text align center
I want to center align textarea with placeholder. so I am using following code
<textarea style="text-align: center" placeholder="Type Here..."></textarea>

But issue is with design. I want to start cursor from starting position of placeholder something like this as like instagram story

but with text-align center it looks like this

I tried different CSS option like padding and setSelectionRange but not working

Where do you want the cursor to be when the user starts typing?

@AHaworth from starting of placeholder. as first first screenshot

And then where does the first character they type go, and then the second and so on. Once they start typing the placeholder disappears so having the cursor part way along the input will look a bit odd as it’s a random position. Does the typing immediately go to the left side as normal for a textarea?

I think that its not directly possible using just the textarea and placeholder and way you can try is by adding the textarea in a div
<div style="border: 1px solid;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
    <textarea style="border: none; resize: none;" placeholder="Type Here..."></textarea>
</div>

You can further style the element as per your need
